# Achieving greatness through torah study

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, talmud-gemara

Is there any source that says when one lowers himself (i.e. his dignity) or suffers embarrassment to learn Torah, he achieves greatness?

Comment: Why the downvotes??

Comment: @ShimonbM I can't speak for others'. Mine is because the question neither (1) gives motivation for seeking such a source (so we know what sorts of sources might be acceptable or how close to his/her phrasing the source should be) nor (2) gives any indication (a) of where Chiddushei Torah has already searched for such a source (so we don't duplicate his/her work) or (b) of anything he/she knows about the principle he/she cites (so we can e.g. start our search in Sephardic works).

Comment: Reading about R Shmuel Wosner z"l. In his yeshiva he never advertised the fact if anyone had received semicha or anything similar.

Comment: http://rabbi-yoshiyahu-pinto.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/blog-post_13.html

Comment: ב. אין דברי תורה מתקיימין במי שמרפה עצמו עליהן ולא באלו שלומדין מתוך עידון ומתוך אכילה ושתיה אלא במי שממית עצמו עליהן ומצער גופו תמיד ולא יתן שינה לעיניו ולעפעפיו תנומה אמרו חכמים דרך רמז זאת התורה אדם כי ימות באהל אין התורה מתקיימת אלא במי שממית עצמו באהלי החכמים וכן אמר שלמה בחכמתו התרפית ביום צרה צר כחכה ועוד אמר אף חכמתי עמדה לי חכמה שלמדתי באף היא עמדה לי אמרו חכמים ברית כרותה שכל היגע בתורתו בבית המדרש לא במהרה הוא משכח וכל היגע בתלמודו בצנעה מחכים שנאמר ואת צנועים חכמה וכל המשמיע קולו בשעת תלמודו תלמודו מתקיים בידו אבל הקורא בלחש במהרה הוא שוכח:

Comment: https://gmara.wordpress.com/%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7-%D7%92/

Answer (score 2):

A beraita (Tana d'Vei Eliyahu §17, Kallah Rabbati §8; cf: Avot 6:6) lists amongst those things that enable a person to acquire Torah patience, acceptance of suffering, recognising one's place and relinquishing any desire for greatness. In a similar fashion, the midrash (Tanchuma, Noach §3) notes that one only acquires Torah if he abandons the pursuit for honour. It would seem to me that the confluence of these character traits (abandoning hope for honour or greatness, together with patience and acceptance of suffering) bespeak a certain abasement of one's own dignity.

In line with this idea, the Mishna (Avot 2:5) notes that one who suffers from embarrassment will never learn, and Orchot Tzadikkim (§2) relates a story concerning one of the "great ones of the generation", in which ascribes his stature to always believing others were better than he. See also Rashi (Nazir 59b, s.v. אמר רב יהודה), who learns out from the Mishna that one should always suggest an answer to something, even if he knows that it is wrong, and even though people will mock him for having said it (ואפילו יודע בו שאין בדבריו ולא כלום ושאר חביריו יהיו מלעיגין עליו).

Answer (score 2):

See the Gemara in Nedarim (55a-b) Rav Yosef says to Rava:

> מאי דכתיב {במדבר כא-יח} וממדבר מתנה וממתנה נחליאל ומנחליאל במות א''ל
>   כיון שעושה אדם את עצמו כמדבר שהוא מופקר לכל תורה ניתנה לו במתנה שנאמר
>   וממדבר מתנה וכיון שניתנה לו במתנה נחלו אל שנאמר וממתנה נחליאל וכיון
>   שנחלו אל עולה לגדולה שנאמר ומנחליאל במות ואם הגביה עצמו הקב''ה משפילו
>   שנאמר {במדבר כא-כ} ומבמות הגיא ולא עוד אלא ששוקעין אותו בקרקע שנאמר
>   {במדבר כא-כ} ונשקפה על פני הישימון ואם חוזר בו הקב''ה מגביהו שנאמר
>   {ישעיה מ-ד} כל גיא ינשא.

When one makes himself as if he is a desert and is open to all,  Hashem will give him the Torah as a present. And if one makes himself haughty ie. Baal Gaavah, Hashem will lower him. However if he repents, does Teshuva, and lowers himself, Hashem will raise him up.

The Ran writes (ד״ה מאי דכתיב) that   Rav Yosef was exhorting Rava to be שפל רוח ביותר- to be exceedingly humble.

We see that to acquire torah one must lower himself, and by doing that Hashem will raise you up.

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara in Megillah 11a says

> שמואל א יז-יד: ודוד הוא הקטן הוא בקטנותו מתחילתו עד סופו כשם שבקטנותו הקטין עצמו אצל מי שגדול ממנו בתורה כך במלכותו הקטין עצמו אצל מי שגדול ממנו בחכמה

"And David was the small one": He remained continually in his smallness. Just as in his youth he lowered himself in from of one who was greater than him in Torah, so too during his reign he lowered himself before one who was greater than him in wisdom."

Although this quote doesn't explicitly write that this attitude led him to achieve greatness, the implication is certainly that this was a positive attribute, and a part of his greatness.

Answer (score 0):

Eiruvin 54b

> א"ר (אליעזר) מאי דכתיב וענקים לגרגרותיך אם משים אדם עצמו כענק זה שרף על הצואר ונראה ואינו נראה תלמודו מתקיים בידו ואם לאו אין תלמודו מתקיים בידו ואמר ר"א מאי דכתיב לחיו כערוגת הבשם אם משים אדם עצמו כערוגה זו שהכל דשין בה וכבושם זה שהכל מתבשמין בה תלמודו מתקיים ואם לאו אין תלמודו מתקיים
>   אמר רב מתנה מאי דכתיב (במדבר כא) וממדבר מתנה אם משים אדם עצמו כמדבר זה שהכל דשין בו תלמודו מתקיים בידו ואם לאו אין תלמודו מתקיים בידו רבא בריה דרב יוסף בר חמא הוה ליה מלתא לרב יוסף בהדיה כי מטא מעלי יומא דכיפורי אמר איזיל ואפייסיה אזל אשכחיה לשמעיה דקא מזיג ליה כסא אמר ליה הב לי ואימזגיה אנא יהב ליה מזגיה כדטעמיה אמר דמי האי מזיגא למזיגא דרבא בריה דרב יוסף בר חמא א"ל אנא הוא א"ל לא תתיב אכרעיך עד דמפרשת לי הני קראי מאי דכתיב (במדבר כא) וממדבר מתנה וממתנה נחליאל ומנחליאל במות ומבמות הגיא א"ל אם אדם משים עצמו כמדבר זה שהכל דשין בו תורה ניתנה לו במתנה וכיון שניתנה לו במתנה נחלו אל שנאמר וממתנה נחליאל וכיון שנחלו אל עולה לגדולה שנאמר ומנחליאל במות ואם מגיס לבו הקדוש ברוך הוא משפילו שנאמר ומבמות הגיא ואם חוזר בו הקב"ה מגביהו שנאמר (ישעיהו מ) כל גיא ינשא
>
> R. Eleazar43 said; What is the purport of the
>   Scriptural text: And chains about thy neck?44
>   If a man trains himself to be like a chain that
>   hangs loosely upon the neck,45 and is
>   sometimes exposed and sometimes
>   concealed,46 his learning will be preserved by
>   him, otherwise it will not.
>   R. Eleazar further stated: What is the
>   purport of the Scriptural text: His cheeks are
>   as a bed of slices?47 If a man allows himself to
>   be treated as a bed upon which everybody
>   treads,48 and as spices with which everybody
>   perfumes himself,49 his learning will be
>   preserved, but otherwise it will not.
>
> ....
>   R. Mattena expounded: What is the purport
>   of the Scriptural text: And from the
>   wilderness to Mattanah?59 If a man allows
>   himself to be treated as a wilderness on which
>   everybody treads, his study will be retained60
>   by him, otherwise it will not.
>   R. Joseph had a grievance against Raba son
>   of R. Joseph b. Hama. When the eve of the
>   Day of Atonement approached the latter
>   thought, ‘I shall go and pacify him’ —
>   Proceeding to R. Joseph's house he found his
>   attendant engaged in mixing for him a cup of
>   wine.61 ‘Give it to me’, Raba62 said to him,
>   ‘and I will mix it’. He gave it to him and the
>   latter duly mixed it. As he63 tasted it, he
>   remarked: ‘This mixing is like that of Raba
>   son of R. Joseph b. Hama’.62 ‘I am here’ the
>   other answered. ‘Do not sit down upon your
>   legs’,64 R. Joseph said to him, ‘before you
>   have explained to me these verses. What is
>   the purport of the Scriptural text: And from
>   the wilderness to Mattanah, and front
>   Mattanah to Nahaliel, and from Nahaliel to
>   Bamoth, and front Bamoth to the valley?’65
>   — ‘If’, the other replied: ‘a man allows
>   himself to be treated as the wilderness upon
>   which everybody treads, the Torah will be
>   given to him as a gift;66 and so soon as it is
>   given to him as a gift, he will be the
>   inheritance of God67 as it says: And from
>   Mattanah66 to Nahaliel;60 and as soon as he is
>   the inheritance of God, he rises to
>   greatness,68 since it says: And from Nahaliel67
>   to Bamoth.68 But if he is haughty, the Holy
>   One, blessed be He, humbles him, as it says:
>   And from Bamoth68 to the valley.69 If,
>   however, he repents, the Holy One, blessed be 
>   He, raises him, as it says: Every valley69 shall
>   be lifted up.70

Source

Brachos 63b

> אמרי דבי ר' ינאי מאי דכתיב כי מיץ חלב יוציא חמאה ומיץ אף יוציא דם ומיץ אפים יוציא ריב במי אתה מוצא חמאה של תורה במי שמקיא חלב שינק משדי אמו עליה ומיץ אף יוציא דם כל תלמיד שכועס עליו רבו פעם ראשונה ושותק זוכה להבחין בין דם טמא לדם טהור ומיץ אפים יוציא ריב כל תלמיד שכועס עליו רבו פעם ראשונה ושניה ושותק זוכה להבחין בין דיני ממונות לדיני נפשות דתנן ר' ישמעאל אומר הרוצה שיתחכם יעסוק בדיני ממונות שאין לך מקצוע בתורה יותר מהן שהן כמעין נובע אמר ר' שמואל בר נחמני מאי דכתיב אם נבלת בהתנשא ואם זמות יד לפה כל המנבל עצמו על דברי תורה סופו להתנשא ואם זמם יד לפה
>
> They said in the school of R. Jannai: What is
>   meant by the verse, For the churning of milk
>   bringeth forth curd, and the wringing of the
>   nose bringeth forth blood; so the forcing of
>   wrath bringeth forth strife?26 With whom do
>   you find the cream of the Torah? With him
>   who spits out upon it the milk which he has
>   sucked from the breasts of his mother.27 'The
>   wringing of the nose28 bringeth forth blood'.
>   Every student who is silent when his teacher
>   is angry with him the first time will become
>   worthy to distinguish between clean blood
>   and unclean. 'The forcing of wrath29 bringeth
>   forth strife': Every student who is silent when
>   his teacher is angry with him a first and a
>   second time will be worthy to distinguish
>   between money cases and capital cases,30 as
>   we have learnt: R. Ishmael says, One who
>   desires to be wise should occupy himself with
>   money judgments, since no branch of the
>   Torah surpasses them, for they are like a
>   perpetual fountain [of instruction]. R. Samuel
>   b. Nahmani said: What is meant by the verse,
>   If thou hast done foolishly [nobaltah] in
>   lifting up thyself, or if thou hast planned
>   devices [zammotah], lay thy hand upon thy
>   mouth?31 Whoever abases [menabbel] himself
>   for words of Torah32 will in the end be
>   exalted, but if one muzzles [zamam] himself,
>   his hand will be upon his mouth.33

[Source](http://halakhah.com/rst/zeraim/01b%20-%20Brochos%20-%2032a-64a.pdf)